# Ipython notebook: in computing SIFT freatures using Python-Opencv: The kernel appears to have died/ in Python:Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, sift

Hi trying to execute the following simple program to detect SIFT features of an image in Ipython notebook, but everytime receiving an error message appears. I googled it, but couldn't find any solutions so far.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import itertools
```

Load Images:

```
img = cv2.imread("galaxy.png")
```

Find Keypoints:

```
detector = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SIFT")
descriptor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SIFT")

skp = detector.detect(img) # in this line kernel dies!!
```

the kernel appears to have died

```
skp, sd = descriptor.compute(img, skp)

tkp = detector.detect(template)
tkp, td = descriptor.compute(template, tkp)
```

my system is Ubuntu 14.04 lts, ipython 3.2.0, python 2.7. 
more over I tried it in python and got this error message:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around, but not a good way. I moved that notebook to another folder which it was the only file in that folder, ran it again and got no error. the bad side is that I need this notebook to be in a specific folder! Really Strange problem. any idea how to solve this problem in a better way!